# What is the LibTorch equivalent to PyTorch's torch.no_grad?

Tags: python, c++, pytorch, autograd, libtorch

When testing a network in PyTorch one can use `with torch.no_grad():`. What is the Libtorch (C++) equivalent?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equivalent in LibTorch is `torch::NoGradGuard no_grad`, [see documentation](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/typedef_namespacetorch_1abf2c764801b507b6a105664a2406a410.html#typedef-torch-nogradguard).

Comment: So I can just use it like this
```torch::NoGradGuard no_grad;```
and every following line operates with no grad?

Comment: Yes. It will affect the current scope you're in by disabling the gradient computation.